# How to update JSON object/array via PUT request?

Tags: json, node.js, crud

Before I even begin, I am so sorry for whatever way I may describe this question - this Node stuff is a little daunting for myself at the minute.

I'm trying to learn Node by making a simple ToDo list application with CRUD capabilities.

I've been able to implement the create and delete functionality of the app, I just can't figure out how to update a certain task to be "complete" within this object:

```
  var data = [
  {
    task: 'Go to shop',
    date: 'Friday Nov 24 2017',
    completed: 1
  },
  {
    task: 'Complete this assignment',
    date: 'Sunday Nov 26 2017',
    completed: 0
  },
  {
    task: 'Give up on NodeJS',
    date: 'Tue Nov 28 2017',
    completed: 1
  }
]
```

**Here's the controller I intend on using:**

```
app.put('/tasks/:task', function(req, res){
// can't figure out what to put in here
});
```

**along with this AJAX request**

```
$('.completed').on('click',  function(){
    var item = $(this).parents('li').find('p');
    var completed = {completed: 1};
    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: '/tasks/' + item,
      data: completed,
      success: function(data){
        location.reload();
      }
    })
  })
```

I was able to somewhat get it to work, although upon clicking the button, the function would just update all tasks to "completed/1"

Answer (score 0):

In your request object, `req` you can access the parameters that are passed to you from the url. In this case you want the `:task` parameter, which represents the index of the target object in your `data` array. Then, you change that object's completed status.

For example:

```
app.put('/tasks/:task', function(req, res){
   data[params['task']]['completed'] = req.data.completed;
});
```

Maybe a bit clearer:

```
app.put('/tasks/:task', function(req, res){
   let taskIndex = params['task'];
   let targetTask = data[taskIndex];
   let postedStatus = req.data.completed;

   targetTask.completed = postedStatus;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add id key to each task object. And usually, ids are unique, so it could be used when you are querying a certain object out of a sequence of data objects.

```
{
  id: 1,
  task: "Now the task has a unique id",
  completed: 0
}
```

Then, instead of using task string, you can use an id on your API url, for example `/tasks/:taskId`.

You PUT routing listener will look like below then

```
app.put("/tasks/:taskId", (req, res, next)=>{
  data.forEach(ele=>{
    if (ele.id === req.params.taskId) ele.completed = 1;
  });
  res.json({// if you will feedback your changed data to the source.
    message: "Completed a task!",
    data: data,
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you out!